# Have a thread start another thread and then die

Tags: java, multithreading

There are 3 threads: Main Thread (thread from which main() runs on), `Thread A` and `Thread B`.

Order of Operations:

- Program Starts (main())
- Main Thread instantiates and starts `Thread A`.
- `Thread A` after X seconds instantiates `Thread B`.
- `Thread B` is started.
- `Thread B` after X seconds instantiates `Thread A`.
- `Thread A` is started.

If the call to `Thread B` is the LAST statement executed in the runnable of `Thread A`, will `Thread A` terminate after `Thread B` is instantiated and started? Or will `Thread B` be nested in `Thread A` and therefore create an infinite number of nested threads? What is the default behaviour and how would I accomplish NOT creating an infinite number of threads (I would like every previous thread to end while the child survives).

A `Thread.join()` would cause the thread to wait until the children thread die, correct?

If this is just bad practice in general, can anyone recommend alternatives that will essentially accomplish the same task? I need one function to, after a few seconds, call another functions which will then run simultaneously with the first function. The first function will then, after completing some commands, die. The second function should then, after a few seconds, call a new instance of the first function. This loop should continue until aborted by the main thread (or until the program exits).

Comment: If you don't want to keep instanciating and destroying a bunch of threads, you could always look into worker thread pools.  The idea is that threads stay around and are given work units that they do and then just wait for more work.  The benefit is that you aren't wasting time with the overhead of constantly killing and spawning threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains the answer: you are thinking of threads as tasks or "functions to run", which they are not. Threads execute tasks, so design your code around the idea of tasks that can create other tasks. Tasks are simply Objects that implement the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, nothing more. You can construct these tasks (or runnable objects) with all the data they need, even including references to other (parent) tasks. 

Create one [CachedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) and whenever a task is ready to be executed, dump the task in the threadpool using the [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

One thing you will need to consider is program shutdown: you need to close the ThreadPool in order to close your program gracefully. You can simply call [shutdownNow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29), but you'll probably want to device a technique that gives important tasks a chance to complete and then shutdown. That will take some practice to get it right ([shutdownHooks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) for example are not easy), but from then on you can re-use it whenever you need more than 1 thread.